# Test-Path Registry key works in Windows Terminal but not in my .ps1 script

Tags: powershell, registry

I am wanting to to test if a registry key exists by using Test-Path:

```
if((Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\IDTSettings') -eq $true) {
    echo "Registry Key Exists, Ignoring this machine."
    exit
}
else {
...
```

I manually created this key in the registry and it looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of regedit for the key that I manually created.]

However, running this script will never exit and instead it will go into the else statement.

To test this I tried `Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\IDTSettings'` in the Windows Terminal and it responded with the appropriate True.

I am confused why these are different and would love if anyone would be able to help with this.

Many thanks

EDIT:

Weirdly if I run the powershell script from Windows Terminal it will detect the registry key fine but If I try to run it from PowerShell ISE it doesn't work. This does fix my problem as the script works properly when I call it so I will close this question.
Thank you all for trying to help :)

Comment: Is that a remote computer?

Comment: It is all on the same local machine @AbrahamZinala.

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue? Are you running the powershell session as elevated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have confirmed, **the problem was that you ran your script from the *32-bit version* of the ISE**, which **sees *different*, 32-bit-application-specific registry information in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` subtree** (which, expressed as a PowerShell path, is equivalent to `HKLM:\SOFTWARE`).

- If use of the 32-bit ISE was accidental (check if the window title ends in  `(x86)`), simply **run the 64-bit version instead** (e.g., run `powershell_ise` from a 64-bit PowerShell or `cmd.exe` session, which launches `C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe`)
- Otherwise, see below.

---

**If you really must test the existence of a key in the 64-bit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` subtree *from a 32-bit process***, more work is needed; one option is to use [`reg.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg):

```
if ($(reg.exe query 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDTSettings' /reg:64 *>$null; -not $LASTEXITCODE)) {
  "Registry key exists, ignoring this machine."
  exit
}
else {
  
  # ...
}
```

Note that the *inverse* solution - accessing a 32-bit key from a 64-bit process would be simpler: the 32-bit data is accessible via the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` subtree
(`if (Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\IDTSettings') { ... }`)

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly if I run the powershell script from Windows Terminal it will detect the registry key fine but If I try to run it from PowerShell ISE it doesn't work. This does fix my problem as the script works properly when I call it so I will close this question. Thank you all for trying to help :)

Comment: One thing worth investigating: are you running the 32-bit version of the ISE? 64-bit processes see different registry hives than 32-bit ones.

Comment: That was it ! I was running ISE(x86) so that is what caused the problem. Thanks for the input @mklement0

Answer (score -1):

You use **Test-Path** cmdlet to see if a key exists. Test-Path can detect registry keys (the containers), but it cannot detect registry entries (sometimes called “values”) or the data in an entry. If you try, it always returns FALSE.

You use **Get-ItemProperty** cmdlet to see the key value

```
$path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Intel\Display\igfxcui\3D"
$value = "Global"

#You can use the Test-Path cmdlet to check for the key, but not for specific values within a key
Test-Path $path

#You can use the Get-ItemProperty to see the value
Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $Value
```

[image: Test Registry Path]

Comment: If I try ```Get-ItemProperty``` I just recieve an error of ```Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\IDTSettings' because it does not exist.``` All I want to do is check if the key exists and I'm not bothered about the value stored inside it. However it can't see the path. I know for a fact that the path does in fact exist.

Comment: I think your missing a slash. $regpath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\IDTSettings\" Get-ItemProperty $regpath

Comment: The question shows that  a registry _key_ - rather than a _value_ - is being tested for existence, so your explanation doesn't apply. Also, whether or not a  trailing `\ ` is part of a registry path passed to `Get-ItemProperty` makes no difference.

Comment: In other words: While the information about `Get-ItemProperty` is helpful in general (as an aside: there's also `Get-ItemPropertyValue`, which obviates the need for the additional `Select-Object` call), it is _unrelated to the question_, which means that your answer not only doesn't explain the OP's problem but amounts to a distraction - unless you at least preface your answer with a note indicating that you're providing tangentially related information only.